# How does someone write a python function?

Tags: python, function

How does someone write a python function that converts a 'date' to the day of the year (e.g. Jan 31st would be the 'date' and 31 would be the day of year, Feb 1st would be the 'date' and 32 would be the day of year).

Comment: As this question is not GIS specific in any way, it would better fit on StackExchange's Programming site: StackOverflow.  As a matter of fact, it is a question on StackOverflow, with some useful answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/623312

Comment: Look [here](https://github.com/s6hebern/scripts/blob/master/Python/date_conversion.py) and adjust at will

Answer (score 1):

You can just [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) your date with `%j`

> %j    Day of the year as a zero-padded decimal number.    001, 002, …, 366

```
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
print today.strftime('%j')
```